# document creation using google APIs in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

Is is possible to give google service-account's access to whole drive instead of just folders?
I'm unable to switch to a new directory using `google docs API` in python. It was possible to jump into a folder and then create the document there using `google drive APIs` but I want to use `docs API` only and I can't see any way to jump into another folder.

Comment: Hi, please notice that you are asking many questions here. I'd suggest you to edit your post in order to focus on a single specific issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sure, I'll update the question.

Comment: By `jump into another folder` you mean moving a file to a different folder? You cannot do this in Docs API, you have to use Drive API for this. May I know why you don't want to use Drive, and just Docs?

Comment: I'm unable to add any content to my doc when I use Drive API. I didn't get any logic which can do batch update using drive APIs. In docs API, it's simply - `result = service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={'requests': requests}).execute()`

Comment: Of course, `batchUpdate` is to be used with Docs API. But for file creation, I'd suggest using Drive API, since you want to add it to a specific folder. Take a look at my answer for more information.

Comment: sure, thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is possible to give google service-account's access to whole drive instead of just folders?

If you have a Workspace domain, I'd suggest granting domain-wide authority to the service account in order to impersonate the regular user's `My Drive` and access everything they can access. See [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) for more details about how to accomplish this.

If this is not an option for you, you should share all top-level items on the Drive, since there's no direct method to share the full `My Drive`.

> It was possible to jump into a folder and then create the document there using google drive APIs but I want to use docs API only and I can't see any way to jump into another folder.

You need to use Drive API to move files between folders. Docs API cannot be used for that.

#### Sidenote:

Not sure if you're aware of this, but please notice that, if you create a document via Docs API, you can only create a blank document, since all fields apart from `title` are ignored in this method (see [documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create)). If you want to add text, change other properties, etc., you'll have to use [documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate).

I'm mentioning this since I don't know whether that was the reason you wanted to create the document via Docs API.

Comment: currently, I'm unable to view the document in my drive when I create it using Google doc API's `documents.create` method since I can't give service account access to whole `My Drive` using Google doc API. So currently I create a document manually in drive then give it service account access and then use its `documentId` to insert data in this document. But I don't want to do this, I want to create the doc using API and give it google account access. Also my account is not a Workspace domain.

Comment: When I use google drive API, I'm able to create a folder in my drive and then able to create a black document inside it but I'm unable to insert any data inside the document since `documents.batchUpdate` won't work in drive APIs.

Comment: @Ask_Ashu Consider the following workflow: (1) Create the file in your desired folder using Drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#create_a_file_in_a_folder, (2) Share the file with the service account using Drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing, (3) Grab the file id, (4) Using the file id, call Docs API's `documents.batchUpdate` to update your file accordingly https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate.

Comment: This approach is also not working. let me update the question with what I'm trying right now.

Comment: @Ask_Ashu Consider posting a new question. Your original question was already answered.

Comment: okay, I'll post a new question